# condition while making relation in YIi

Tags: yii

Agent:

`agent_id  (primary key)`

User:

```
f_id (foreign key)
type
```

I have created relation in this way

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Users', 'f_id'),
    );
}
```

But I want to add more conditions like join only if *`type=3`* in User table.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add the condition on your relation

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Users', 'f_id', array(
            'condition' => 'user.type = :type',
            'params' => array(':type'=>3)
        )),
    );
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options

Comment: Property "CHasOneRelation.0" is not defined.  showup with bunch of errors. Any clue ?

Comment: @abnab how do you get the error? does your code before run perfectly or still return any errors?

Comment: yup it worked fine ..just used to get wrong relation as type was not defined ..but now that errors come up

Answer (score 10):

There is no error like 'Property "CHasOneRelation.0" is not defined' if you use this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(
            self::HAS_ONE, 
            'Users', 
            'f_id',
            'on' => 'user.ref_type = :type', 
            'params' => array(':type' => 3))
    );
}
```

See this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10185-using-relations-and-conditions/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function to get user rather use lazy-load which would use more query even you do not use this relation.

```
public function getUser(){
    return Users::model()->find(array(
        'condition'=>'type = :type', 
        'params' => array(':type'=>3)
    ));  
}
```

By using this you could use cache function to cache query that relation does not support.

```
public function getUser(){
    return Users::model()->cache(1000)->find(array(
        'condition'=>'type = :type', 
        'params' => array(':type'=>3)
    ));  
}
```

Comment: Works. I used `'columns' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Column', 'presentation_id', 'on' => 'columns.onDeleted IS NOT NULL'),`