# Property "CHasOneRelation.limit" is not defined

Tags: php, database, yii

How to get rid of this error: `Property "CHasOneRelation.limit" is not defined.`

here is my relation method:

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'documents' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Document', 'dossier_id',),
            'lastLogline' => array(
                self::HAS_ONE, 
                'Logline ll', 
                'dossier_id',
                'limit'              => 1,
                'order'              => 'll.create_date DESC'),
            'lastmodifiedUser'   => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'User', 'lastmodified_user_id',),
            'loglines' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Logline', 'dossier_id',),
            'priority' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Priority', 'priority_id',),
            'properties' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Property', 'doe_dossier_has_property(dossier_id,property_id)',),
            'state' => array(
                self::HAS_ONE,
                'State',
                'doe_logline(dossier_id,state_id) ll',
                'limit'  => 1,
                'order'  => 'll.create_date DESC'),
        );
    }
```

then when I go to my web page I get his following error:

```
    /vagrant/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(2011)

1999      * Constructor.
2000      * @param string $name name of the relation
2001      * @param string $className name of the related active record class
2002      * @param string $foreignKey foreign key for this relation
2003      * @param array $options additional options (name=>value). The keys must be the property names of this class.
2004      */
2005     public function __construct($name,$className,$foreignKey,$options=array())
2006     {
2007         $this->name=$name;
2008         $this->className=$className;
2009         $this->foreignKey=$foreignKey;
2010         foreach($options as $name=>$value)
2011             $this->$name=$value;
2012     }
2013 
2014     /**
2015      * Merges this relation with a criteria specified dynamically.
2016      * @param array $criteria the dynamically specified criteria
2017      * @param boolean $fromScope whether the criteria to be merged is from scopes
2018      */
2019     public function mergeWith($criteria,$fromScope=false)
2020     {
2021         if($criteria instanceof CDbCriteria)
2022             $criteria=$criteria->toArray();
2023         if(isset($criteria['select']) && $this->select!==$criteria['select'])
```

How is this possible to solve this problem??

when I was searching the web I found this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891294/condition-while-making-relation-in-yii), and also this [one](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/48063-limit-for-has-one-relation/page__p__224776__hl__CHa+OneRelation#entry224776) but it wasnt that helpful to me.

Comment: I have added this to my relation: 'condition'=>'LIMIT 1' but it didnt help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot put a limit on a has one relation as you've already said HAS_ONE. CHasOneRelation now knows it needs to find one relating record.

limit is only used on the main query to declare how many rows you need.

Do not put in table aliasses as :  'Logline ll', . the alias is the lastLogline (the array definition).

Comment: also if you have to insert a limit of 1 then rather use find instead of findAll.

Comment: I also had this problem. In my case I was using a class and in that class, I had a relationship of HAS_ONE but I also added a 'limit'=>1 on it. The request that caused this did **not** use this relation. Rather, the exception was thrown when the class was parsed - when I used another functionality of it. All in all, Yii's message here gives you a good hint of the problem.